# Missing latin characters on Mono GDI+

Tags: unicode, raspberry-pi, mono, gdi+

There is an issue and so far I'm unable to solve it. I have a program written in Mono with GDI+ forms and controls. It seems that there is something wrong with the following unicode characters: ĉ, ċ, č (both upper and lowercase), from U+0108 to U+010D. It occurs on all controls (TextBox, Button, Label etc.) as well as when using DrawString() function. If I write 'ĉĉĉĉĉĉ' on TextBox, only the first character is displayed properly. If the string ends with any other character than ĉ, ċ or č, it is drawn correctly, otherwise the characters at the end are not displayed.

It seems that this is not a font issue, tested with Arial and some other random fonts.

Tested on:

- Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS + Mono 5.4.1.7
- Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch) + Mono 5.10.0.160

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: try to create a simple python program that does the same, to rule out if it's a GTK bug or a Mono bug.

Comment: @knocte sorry, my bad. It's GDI+ (WinForms), not GTK+.
And Mono's DrawString function calls libgdiplus function.

https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/e33294bf2217e2bbe20dc6462af7b1989d12e72f/mcs/class/System.Drawing/System.Drawing/Graphics.cs#L1190

Comment: try it then in Microsoft.NET + Windows, if it behaves differently then report a Mono bug; if it behaves the same way you might be misunderstanding .NET API :)

Comment: Gdi+ in Win32 expects wide string characters `DrawString(L"str", ...)` I don't know how that translates for Linux libraries. Try `DrawString(u8"str", ...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in libgdiplus library in text-cairo.c
I fixed it and made PR.